# Trello-like CSS Grid-Layout: how can I scroll the card list and have the title and the footer visible

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, trello

I am trying to build a Trello-like UI based on css grid-Layouts. I followed an extremely helpful tutorial by Joshua Saunders (https://medium.com/better-programming/creating-trellos-ui-with-css-grid-ed1fbfcd9448)
At the end it is unfinished though and I have been looking for a solution all day:
Trello has a specific behaviour for it's card lists when resizing the browser-window: if the list  hasn't reached the bottom-end of the viewport, the "+ add card"-Button is always at the end of the list and all cards are visible. If the card list is too long for the viewport, the "+ add card"-button will always still be visible at the bottom end of the viewport, but the card list between title and "+ add card"-button becomes scrollable.

In summary: At any viewport-size, the title and the "+ add card"-button of each list will always be visible, the card-list itself becomes scrollable if necessary.  I think, I found a solution with flex-layouts (haven't tried it yet), but I am still wondering, if it is possible with grid-layouts.

Here is my Code:

```css
BODY {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.base {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: rgb(0, 121, 191);
    font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Noto Sans,Ubuntu,Droid Sans,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: max-content auto;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
.header {
    padding:5px;
    color:white;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.board {
    margin:5px;
    height:auto;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:max-content;
    overflow:auto;
    grid-auto-flow:column;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.lists {
    height:auto;
    display:grid;
    grid-auto-columns:272px;
    grid-auto-flow:column;
    grid-gap:8px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.list {
    background-color:rgb(235, 236, 240);
    border-radius:3px;
    padding:10px;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-rows:max-content auto max-content;
    grid-gap:10px;
    height:max-content;
    align-items:stretch;
}
.list-title {
    font-weight:bold;
}
.list-body {
    display:grid;
    grid-auto-rows:max-content;
    grid-gap:10px;
    height:max-content;
    overflow:scroll;
}
.card {
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:3px;
    box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(9, 30, 66, 0.25);
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>grid-layout trello-like UI - heightproblem</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="trello-ui.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="base">
    <div class="header">
        Header
    </div>
    <div class="board">
        <div class="lists">
        
            <div class="list">
                <div class="list-title">List 1</div>
                <div class="list-body">
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                </div><!--// list-body -->
                <div class="list-foot">+ add card</div>
            </div><!--// list -->
            
        
            <div class="list">
                <div class="list-title">List 2</div>
                <div class="list-body">
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                </div><!--// list-body -->
                <div class="list-foot">+ add card</div>
            </div><!--// list -->
            
            <div class="list">
                <div class="list-title">List 3</div>
                <div class="list-body">
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                </div><!--// list-body -->
                <div class="list-foot">+ add card</div>
            </div><!--// list -->
            
            
            <div class="list">
                <div class="list-title">List 4</div>
                <div class="list-body">
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                </div><!--// list-body -->
                <div class="list-foot">+ add card</div>
            </div><!--// list -->
            
            
            <div class="list">
                <div class="list-title">List 5</div>
                <div class="list-body">
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                    <div class="card">Card</div>
                </div><!--// list-body -->
                <div class="list-foot">+ add card</div>
            </div><!--// list -->
            
            <div class="list">
                <div class="list-title">List 6</div>
                <div class="list-body">
                        &nbsp;
                </div><!--// list-body -->
                <div class="list-foot">+ add card</div>
            </div><!--// list -->
            
            
        </div><!--// lists
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the css `calc()` method to calculate the amount of height available, here is it's docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

and here is the solution to your current problem

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.base {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: rgb(0, 121, 191);
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Noto Sans, Ubuntu, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: max-content auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.header {
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 35px;
}

.board {
  margin: 5px;
  height: calc(100vh - 70px);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.lists {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 272px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: calc(100vh - 90px);
}

.list {
  background-color: rgb(235, 236, 240);
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: max-content auto max-content;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: max-content;
  align-items: stretch;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 90px);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 20px;
}

.list-body {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: max-content;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  overflow: scroll;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 190px);
}

.card {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(9, 30, 66, 0.25);
  padding: 10px;
}

.list-foot {
  height: 35px;
}
```